# Python 404'ing on urllib.request

Tags: python, web-scraping

The basics of the code are below. I know for a fact how I'm retrieving these pages works for other URLs, as I just wrote a script scraping a different page in the same way. However with this specific URL it keeps throwing **"urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found"** in my face. I replaced the URL with a different one (https://www.premierleague.com/clubs), and it works completely fine. I'm very new to python so perhaps there's a really basic step or piece of knowledge I haven't found, but resources I've found on line relating to this didn't seem relevant. Any advice would be great, thanks.

Below is the barebones of the script:

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv

myurl = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/premier-league/startseite/wettbewerb/GB1"

uClient = uReq(myurl)
```

Comment: it just means that the server is telling you the page doesn't exist. It *doesn't want to serve your script the page*, perhaps because they want to stop people from scraping it. There isn't anything we can do to help though.

Comment: Guessing the problem is that spiders crawling might be blocked; you can change the user agent to circumvent it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48489443/urllib-error-httperror-http-error-404-not-found-python for more information (The solution prescribed in that post seems to work for your url too) (If you want to use urllib [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226781/changing-user-agent-in-python-3-for-urrlib-request-urlopen) tells you how to alter the user agent).

Comment: Ah I see, interesting. Didn't know that was a thing. @jpw that's pretty much solved it for me, so if you fancy making this an answer I can choose as a solution

Comment: @Danny Sure, reposting my comment as the answer. happy to have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that the site you are trying to access is actively blocking spiders crawling; you can change the user agent to circumvent it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48489443/urllib-error-httperror-http-error-404-not-found-python) for more information (the solution prescribed in that post seems to work for your url too).

If you want to use urllib [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226781/changing-user-agent-in-python-3-for-urrlib-request-urlopen) tells you how to alter the user agent.

Answer (score -1):

It is showing a 404 because it thinks the website doesn't exist.

You can try with a different module like requests.

This is the code for requests

```py
import requests

resp = requests.get("https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/premier-league/startseite/wettbewerb/GB1")

print(resp.text) # gets source code
```

I hope it works!